# Regex to extract date range from a long string

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the whole string

```
Now that your RV has been booked, we will deposit $152.00 into your account 24 hours after #### picks up your RV.
We will also hold the $500.00 security deposit to cover any unforseen costs.

Booking Details
Tab Teardrop - Hip Modern Travel Trailer
Trailer - Sleeps 2
Friday, July 31, 2020 - Sunday, August 2, 2020

Pickup Details
Friday, July 31, 2020
```

I want to extract only this part **using regular expression**.

```
Tab Teardrop - Hip Modern Travel Trailer
Trailer - Sleeps 2
Friday, July 31, 2020 - Sunday, August 2, 2020
```

Comment: Scan lines until you find "Booking Details" and fill a buffer till you reach an empty line.

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you just gotta write your own parser.

A regular expression would be too complicated for this task.

```js
const originalText = document.querySelector('.hidden').value.trim();

const parseInvoice = (input, target) => {
  const lines = input.split('\n'), buffer = [];
  let isActive = false, line;
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    line = lines[i];
    if (line === target) {
      isActive = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (isActive && line.trim().length === 0) {
      break;
    }
    if (isActive) {
      buffer.push(line);
    }
  }
  return buffer.join('\n');
};

console.log(parseInvoice(originalText, 'Booking Details'));
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<textarea class="hidden">
Now that your RV has been booked, we will deposit $152.00 into your account 24 hours after #### picks up your RV.
We will also hold the $500.00 security deposit to cover any unforeseen costs.

Booking Details
Tab Teardrop - Hip Modern Travel Trailer
Trailer - Sleeps 2
Friday, July 31, 2020 - Sunday, August 2, 2020

Pickup Details
Friday, July 31, 2020
</textarea>
```

You could simplify the expression to this.

```js
const parseInvoice = (input, target) => {
  let isActive = false;
  return input.split('\n').filter(line => {
    if (line === target) { isActive = true; return false; }
    if (isActive && line.trim().length === 0) { isActive = false; return false; }
    return isActive;
  }).join('\n');
};
```

If you want to only scan until the first empty line, you will need a another flag, but keep in mind that filter will scan every line. If you only want to scan the minimum number of lines, you should use `Array.prototype.some` or `Array.prototype.every`.

```js
const parseInvoice = (input, target) => {
  let isActive = false, done = false;
  return input.split('\n').filter(line => {
    if (done) return false;
    if (line === target) {
      isActive = true; return false;
    }
    if (isActive && line.trim().length === 0) {
      isActive = false; done = true; return false;
    }
    return isActive;
  }).join('\n');
};
```

If you want to match using a regular expression, you could modify the function to take start and an end expression. There are so many ways you could implement this. It's up to you to decide.

```js
const parseInvoice = (input, startExpr, endExpr, keepMatches) => {
  const lines = input.split('\n'), buffer = [];
  let isActive = false, line;
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    line = lines[i];
    if (line.match(startExpr)) {
      isActive = true;
      if (keepMatches) buffer.push(line);
      continue;
    }
    if (isActive && line.match(endExpr)) {
      if (keepMatches) buffer.push(line);
      break;
    }
    if (isActive) {
      buffer.push(line);
    }
  }
  return buffer.join('\n');
};

console.log(parseInvoice(originalText, /^Booking Details$/, /^$/, true));
```